# Browser not identifying the host entries

Tags: macos, dns, localhost, host

I updated the host file entries as `192.168.0.7     www.mywebsite.com` and then flushed the DNS caches using 
`dscacheutil -flushcache`,
`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

When I ping the `www.mywebsite.com` from terminal, it is getting pinged. But from browser, **Site can't be reached** error is coming.

Do I need to do some more configurations?

OS - **MacOS High Sierra** version **10.13.6**

Edit: complete error

```
This site can’t be reached
www.mywebsite.com refused to connect.
Search Google for mywebsite
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: What are the full details of the error? Is it saying it cannot resolve the hostname, or that it can't connect? Just because you can ping the host doesn't mean it's listening on port 80/443 (http/https) such that the browser can connect to it.

Comment: @cody updated details.

Comment: Ok, so that error makes it clear this is not a DNS issue. It's resolving the host fine, it just can't connect. If you're just using basic http, is `192.168.0.7` listening on port 80? Could there be a firewall or something preventing you from connecting?

Comment: @cody it's on port `3000`. I can access `http://192.168.0.7:3000/`. No firewalls.

Comment: If it would be a DNS issue, the error should be `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. Right?

Comment: It's not a browser cache issue, because I just installed fresh firefox and same error is there also